# pandas : Indexing for thousands of rows in dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing

I initially had 100k rows in my dataset. I read the csv using pandas into a dataframe called data. I tried to do a subset selection of 51 rows using `.loc`. My index labels are numeric values 0, 1, 2, 3 etc. I tried using this command -
`data = data.loc['0':'50']`
But the results were weird, it took all the rows from 0 to 49999, looks like it is taking rows till the index value starts with 50.

Similarly, I tried with this command - `new_data = data.loc['0':'19']`
and the result was all the rows, starting from 0 till 18999.

Could this be a bug in pandas?

Comment: Try `data.loc[0:50, :] ` or `data.ix[0:50] `, without single quotes `'`.

Comment: not sure if it’s  a pandas syntax thing but first thing that i see are the quotes wrapping the numbers you’re using to slice.. vanilla python you slice with actual numbers not strings

Comment: You want `data.iloc[:50,:]`

Comment: slicing by index should be using `.iloc` not `.loc` . And use number instead of string

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `.iloc` in place of `.loc`, since you are selecting data from the dataframe via numeric indices.

For example:

```
data.iloc[:50,:]
```

Keep in mind that your indices are of numeric-type, not string-type, so querying with a string (as you have done in your OP) attempts to match string-wise comparisons.